# Get the radio button value through ajax to php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

After clicking the radio button, the value from the radio button is not being passed when the *onclick* event is triggered. Here is my code:

```php
<form name="Form1" id="color" style="font-size: 100%" action="#">  
    <input type="radio"  name="radio1"  id="radio1" onclick = "MyAlert()" value="blue"/>Blue  <br /></p>  
<p> <input type="radio"  name="radio1" id="radio1" onclick = "MyAlert()" value="red"/>Red  
</form>  

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
function MyAlert()  {  
    var radio1=$('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
    var pass_data = {
            'radio1' : radio1,
        };
        alert(pass_data);
        $.ajax({
            url : "",
            type : "POST",
            data : pass_data,
            success : function(data) {
            }
        });
        return false;
    }  
</script>
<?php
    echo $radio1=$_GET['radio1'];
?>
```

When I click the radio button, I get the error

> Undefined index: radio1

I want to display value of the radio button when clicking it within the same page.

Comment: `$_GET['radio1'];` and `type : "POST",` dont match.. choose wisely

Comment: What kind of a question is this?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly make ajax to separate PHP page where you will access the radio value. Also make alert after you receive the data.

```
$.ajax({
    url : "post.php",
    type : "POST",
    data: pass_data,
    success : function(data) {
        // alert radio value here
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Crete a separate PHP file post.php where you access radio input. Since you are making POST request you need to use $_POST instead of $_GET to get radio button value.

```
<?php 
    $radio1 = $_POST['radio1'];
    echo $radio1;
?>
```

Comment: good but selected value alert is came but i want to print that value

Comment: Add <div id="color"></div> in html and replace alert(data) with $("#color").html(data). This will print ajax request to div instead of alert.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <input type="radio"  id="status" name="status" value="1" /> Mbyllur<br />
  <input type="radio"  id="status" name="status" value="0" /> Hapur<br />


  function MyAlert()  
      {  
  var radio1=$('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
  var pass_data = {
                    'radio1' : $('input[name=status]:checked').val(),
              };
              alert(pass_data);
              $.ajax({
                    url : "",
                    type : "POST",
                    data : pass_data,
                    success : function(data) {
                    }
              });
              return false;
      }
```

Comment: I want without refresh the page and when i click on hapur it shows the click value

Comment: than just use this $('input[name=status]:checked').val();

Comment: I tried this one $('input[name=status]:checked').val(); but click value not showing

Comment: what do you mean by click value?

Comment: sorry selected radio button value

Comment: use this one $('input[type=radio]:checked').val()

Answer (score 0):

1. I would use a newer version of jquery .
2. You can't give two elements the same id.
3. I would rewrite the code as follow :

```js
$(function() {
 $(document).on('change', '[name="radio1"]' , function(){
   var val = $('[name="radio1"]:checked').val();
    alert(val);

    
    /* 

    Ajax code 1 (GET) : 
    $.get('/myurl?val='  + val, function(){

    });


    Ajax code 2 (POST) : 
    $.post('/myurl', {val : val},  function(){

    });

    */
  }); 

});
```

```html
<form name="Form1" id="color" style="font-size: 100%" action="#" >  
<input type="radio"  name="radio1" value="blue"/>Blue  <br />
<p> <input type="radio"  name="radio1" value="red"/>Red  
</form>  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: but i did not want alert i want to echo the value within the page

Comment: This is just an example on how to get the value, you can use it however you want. You can easily write it into an element : 
$('.myspan').text(val); 

you can write it into the console : 
console.log(val); 

or any other use for that value .

Comment: How to get the same value to print within the page after script tag in php.

Comment: I recommend you add a div and write the value into that div : $('.mydiv').text(val); 

if you want to write the value into the page than here's the code : $('body').append(val)

Answer (score 0):

Try This -->

```
<form name="Form1" id="color" style="font-size: 100%" action="#" >  
    <input type="radio"  name="radio1"  id="radio1" onclick = "MyAlert()" value="blue"/>Blue  <br /></p>  
    <p> <input type="radio"  name="radio1" id="radio1" onclick = "MyAlert()" value="red"/>Red  
    </form>



<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
function MyAlert()  
    {  
var radio1=$('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
//alert(radio1);
var pass_data = {
            'radio1' : radio1,
        };
        //alert(pass_data);
        $.ajax({
            url : "request.php",  // create a new php page to handle ajax request
            type : "POST",
            data : pass_data,
            success : function(data) {
            }
        });
        return false;
    }  
</script>
```

> request.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['radio1']))
{
    echo $radio1=$_POST['radio1'];
}
?>
```

Above code handle with ajax so, its not refresh the page.

Comment: i want the value within the page in ajax set the url is empty

Comment: @narendra so, you want to set response value another variable. and ajax file should be same (as you told URL empty).

Comment: if you want like then add below code to the top of file <?php
if(isset($_POST['radio1']))
{
    echo $radio1=$_POST['radio1'];
    die;
}
?>

Comment: ok but i don't want to redirect the value to another page i need selected value within the page

Comment: i want to echo the value but it getting alert

Comment: you will get the response in success 
success : function(data) {
            }
so can will assign the output to perticular element which you want like $("#elementid").html(data) OR $("#elementid").val(data)

Comment: thank you but i did not created request.php  Is there any way to print within the page and without refresh the page.

Comment: After refresh the page it is printed i want without refresh the page and print when i click on radio button within the page.

Comment: you want to print any specific content of page like there are 2 div blue and red. After selection of blue Blue div will print OR vice versa.

Comment: i am getting these values from database foreach loop how can i put 2 div. there is only 1 div is there.  $.ajax({
            url : " ",  // create a new php page to handle ajax request
            type : "POST",
            data : pass_data,
            success : function(data) {
            }
        });
        return false;
    }  Now how to get the selected value

Comment: you can get the selected value with   radio1=$('input[type="radio"]:checked').val(); and pass this to ajax --- var pass_data = {
   'radio1' : radio1,
  };

Comment: ok but after success the ajax how to get and print the selected value within the page

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#Enviar").click(function (e) {

            var cedula = document.getElementById("Cedula").value;
            var Nombre = document.getElementById("Nombre").value;
            var Apellido = document.getElementById("Apellido").value;
            var Sexo = $('input:radio[name=SexoC]:checked').val();
            var Edad = document.getElementById("Edad").value;
            var FechaN = document.getElementById("date").value;
            var Tele = document.getElementById("tel").value;
            var Direccion = document.getElementById("Direccion").value;
            var Invitacion = document.getElementById("Invitacion").value;
            var CasaG = document.getElementById("CasaG").value;
            var Rango = document.getElementById("Rango").value;

            var cadena = "Cedula="+cedula+"&Nombre="+Nombre+"&Apellido="+Apellido+"&Sexo="+Sexo+"&Edad="+Edad+"&Fecha="+FechaN+"&Tele="+Tele+"&Direccion="+Direccion+"&Invitacion="+Invitacion+"&CasaG="+CasaG+"&Rango="+Rango;

                    $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:'datos/Registrar.php',
                        data: cadena,
                        beforeSend: function(){
                        console.log(cadena);
                     },
                        success:function(Resp){
                            alert(Resp);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;

        });
    });
        </script>
```

Comment: Please offer some guidance or comments so that we, readers, learn more about your approach. Thank you