# Save radio button value to database on click ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I successfully save radio button value to database on click with ajax. My issue is when I go back to select again nothing happen in the database, it's only done if I select it once. What can be wrong with my codes. The value in the alert pops up only once as well, it's not pop up if I click again. To be conclude the click works only once.

```
<?php 
$sql="SELECT * FROM medico_precio_plan ORDER BY precio ASC";
$query=$this->db->query($sql);
foreach($query->result() as $rowp)
{
if($rowp->id==$row->payment_plan){
$checked='checked';
}else{
$checked='';

}
?>
<input type="radio" name="plan-pago" <?=$checked?> value='<?=$rowp->id?>'>

<?php } ?>



$(document).ready(function(){  

$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
var plan= $(this).val();
alert(plan);
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
url:'<?=base_url('paypal/update_account_doctor')?>',
data: {plan:plan},
cache: false,
success:function(data) {
$('#reload-plan').html(data);

}

});
})
})
```

Comment: I wonder how you unchecked the radio input while you have just one radio input .. you should have at least two radio inputs with a same name to toggle checked between them .. if you've just one and need to catch the value when checked and unchecked use `checkbox` type

Comment: If you check it well the radio buttons are from a loop, there are 2 radio button.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution from that post: [Get the radio button value through ajax to php file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37314341/get-the-radio-button-value-through-ajax-to-php-file)

```
$(function() {
$(document).on('change', '[name="plan-pago"]' , function(){
var plan = $('[name="plan-pago"]:checked').val();
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
// dataType: 'json',
url:'<?=base_url('paypal/update_account_doctor')?>',
data: {plan:plan,id_doctor:<?=$id_doctor?>},
cache: false,
success:function(data) {
$('#reload-plan').html(data);

}

});


}); 

});
```